# QWebEngine: print a page?

Tags: c++, qt, printing, qt5, qt5.5

The migration from `QWebKit` to `QWebEngine` seems to be much more complicated than Qt guys claimed. With QWebKit I could print a webpage easily via

```
QWebView->print(&printer);
```

With `QWebEngine` class `QWebEngine` view does not provide a method `print()`. Their browser example uses a class named `QWebEngineFrame` which offers a method `print()` - but the whole `QWebEngineFrame` is not defined anywhere!

So my question: how do I print a page using `QWebEngine`?

Comment: Seems a little bit hacky, but does printing work if you call JavaScript inside a webpage: window.print() ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the correct way to use `QWebEngineView::render` method because `QWebEngineView` is a `QWidget`. It accepts paint device as a first argument and you may pass `QPrinter` there for printing.

**Update**: If you can use the latest version of Qt, in Qt 5.8 a new function for printing page was added:

```
void QWebEnginePage::print(QPrinter *printer, FunctorOrLambda resultCallback);
```

Actually it first prints to temp PDF with `QPrinter` settings.

Here is the link to Qt [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#print).

You can read about this in our [blog](http://blog.elangroup-software.com/2016/11/new-print-option-for-qtwebengine-in-qt.html) also.

Comment: This is not really a solution - try to print a page which is larger than what can be displayed visibly and you wil understand where the limits are ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I would offer following code (for a while):

```
    QTextEdit *textEdit = new QTextEdit;
    ui.myWebView->page()->toHtml([textEdit](const QString &result){ textEdit->setHtml(result); });
    textEdit->print(somerinter);
    textEdit->deleteLater();
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine for simple printing of some HTML:

`QTextEdit *textEdit = new QTextEdit;
textEdit->setHtml(td.toHtml());
textEdit->print(_printer);
textEdit->deleteLater();` where td is a QTextDocument.

Answer (score 2):

Qt 5.7 includes print support in to pdf files for [QWebEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html#print-to-pdf).

Use [printToPdf](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#printToPdf) function to export the current page in a pdf file. Example:

```
const QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(0,
                                                tr("Save pdf"),
                                                ".",
                                                tr("PDF Files (*.pdf)"));
if (fileName.isEmpty()) {
    return;
}
ui->webView->page()->printToPdf(fileName);
```

Comment: It should be noted that the printToPdf() method adds static text "PAGE 2:" to the top of the 2nd page, and so on, and this is not configurable.

Additionally, there is no way to add custom headers/footers to each page. If these two things don't bother you, it's a great simple solution and works even when the document spans multiple pages.

Answer (score 1):

`QWebView->page()->print(&printer, [=](bool){});`

Comment: true for Qt 5.8 or newer but for sure not for 5.5

Comment: Yes, this is for Qt >= 5.8