# Qt Webengine Render to Print

Tags: windows, qt, render, qtwebengine

Is there any way to render HTML/SVG to printer, PDF, and raster images with QtWebEngine?

We want to switch from WebKit to WebEngine, so using WebKit's QWebView is not an option anymore.

Comment: You can still use QWebView::print(). QtWebEngine does not supports printing yet (Qt 5.6)

Comment: Well, depending in the HTML support required, you may try QTextDocument, since it has some limited HTML support, but can be good enough (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is announced that Qt Web Engine will support printing to PDF in [Qt 5.7](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.7) which is in beta now.

Two overloads of [printToPdf()](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.7/qwebenginepage.html#printToPdf) function were added in Qt 5.7 for QWebEnginePage class.

We have example how to use these new functions in our company [blog](http://blog.elangroup-software.com/2016/05/qtwebengine-printing-to-pdf.html).

You can look for some already available Qt Web Engine printing options also here:

[QWebEngine: print a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711901/qwebengine-print-a-page/32712296#32712296)

Comment: But there is still no way to print to a print dialog/real printer & paper'

Comment: @swaechter Yes, unfortunately there is no idea when this will be implemented, see [here](https://trello.com/c/JE5kosmC/72-printing-support)

Comment: I really like Qt, but that's just lame (Think about all the business customers that have to print their invoices/bills/reports in their application etc). I guess I'll print it to PDF and use poppler for rendering/printing

Answer (score 1):

It took a bit of tinkering to get printing callable from a worker-thread:

```
void printToPDF(const QString& html, const QString& fileName)
{
    #if QT_VERSION >= 0x057000
    QtWebEngine::initialize();
    QWebEnginePage page;
    QEventLoop loop;
    loop.connect(&page, &QWebEnginePage::loadFinished, [&page, &loop, &fileName]() {
        page.printToPdf([&loop, &fileName] (QByteArray ba) {
            QFile f(fileName);
            if (f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
            {
                f.write(ba);
                f.close();
            } else {
                qDebug() << "Error opening file for writing" << fileName << f.errorString();
            }
            loop.exit();
        });
    });
    page.setHtml(html);
    loop.exec();
    #endif
}
```