# Qt 5.7: using QWebEngine headless

Tags: c++, qt

I've noticed that the QWebEngineView is a QWidget. Is it possible to render html pages for print to PDF in headless mode? Chrome/Chromium can run headless, so it shouldn't be impossible?

I'm making an application that runs on my Linux server (without X), where I would need to install 37 packages to run a virtual framebuffer with xvfb. I would prefer to solve this in another way if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this solves your problem, but you do not need to create an instance of QWebEngineView but only QWebEnginePage. QWebEnginePage is also in the QWebEngineWidgets module, though.. so you will have to build/link against it nonetheless.

For example code see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40307287/3544674

Comment: Linking isn't that big of a deal, but could I use this in a console app?

Comment: Yes, you can - no widgets required.

Comment: This is not correct. You cannot use it in console application.

Comment: JS will report 0x0 size window though.