# in QT, how to convert html with javascript called inside to pdf file

Tags: javascript, html, qt, pdf-generation

***My application is based on qt quick.So widget is not supported.*** I am trying to convert a html file to pdf, which has javascript inside.
the html as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ECharts</title>
</head> 
<body>      
<div id="main" style="width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
**<script src="echarts.js"></script>**
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
```

is there any way to convert this html file to pdf with javascript taking effect?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a web rendering engine to consume the input and execute the script accordingly, then let it print the result.

For example using [QWebEnginePage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html) and one if its `printToPdf()` functions.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to use this under qt quick application? our project is based on this.

Comment: Depends on whether you want to display the HTML content as well as print it. If you want to display it, use a `WebEngineView` element in `QtQuick`. The `QWebEnginePage` class doesn't have or need any UI, so if you are only concerned about interpreting and printing the HTML content, you can still use it in your C++ part of the application

Answer (score 0):

See this stack question: [QWebEngine: print a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711901/qwebengine-print-a-page)

You will find the correct way to print a webview by using new engine based in Chromium or the older webkit. The two options are completly compatible with Qt Quick.

You also could use a [QTextView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#print) to print the data by loading the HTML inside.